# GUI for On / Off Display using Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a function where if I press "1" my image changes, but if I press 1 again the image reverts back to how it was. This process should go on indefinitely.

I am able to do this if the user clicks on a button. For example, the below code simply uses config to change the function that should be run each time button is clicked.

```
# run this "thing" each time seat is activated
def activate(name):
    name.config(image=active)
    name.config(command=lambda: deactivate(name))
    
# run this "thing" each time seat is deactivated
def deactivate(name):
    name.config(image=deactive)
    name.config(command=lambda: activate(name))

x = Button(root, image=deactive, command=lambda: thing(x))
```

But I am unable to achieve the same if I bind a key instead:

```
from tkinter import *

# window config

root = Tk()

root.title("Example - on / off")

root.geometry("1080x600")

# on and off images

inactive = PhotoImage(file='green.png')
active = PhotoImage(file='red.png')

# functions to change the image using config

def something(event):

    my_label.config(image=active)

def something2():

    my_label.config(image=inactive)

#  label which stores the image
my_label = Label(root, image=inactive)
my_label.pack()


# invisible button bind to key "1"
my_button = Button(root)
my_button.bind_all(1, something)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I would welcome any thoughts on this or an indication if I am approaching this completely wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You can use ```mouse``` left and right button to do this by bind them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the logic by using `itertools.cycle()` and `next()` functions:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

root = Tk()
root.title("Example - on / off")
root.geometry("1080x600")

# on and off images
images = cycle((PhotoImage(file='green.png'), PhotoImage(file='red.png')))

def something(event):
    my_label.config(image=next(images))

my_label = Label(root, image=next(images))
my_label.pack()

root.bind('1', something)
root.mainloop()
```